# Is there a limit for inserting number of images in google sheets

Tags: image, google-sheets

I have inserted over 10,060 images into my google sheet (mostly Rubik's cube algorithms and their cube diagram). They are 40-45BB PNG image, and I use the operation, `Insert -> Image -> Image in cell` to insert the image.

Suddenly after 2 years, and filling in over 10k images in one column I get this error message,

[image: Error Message]

Is there a limit on the number of images we can insert into one sheet?

Comment: While a limit regarding the quantity of images or the size doesn't seem to be officially documented (see [official limits](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en)), you are probably reaching a limit. In order to make sure that's the case, if you remove one of the existing images, can you insert a new one? Also, are all images in the same sheet, or in different sheets from the same spreadsheet? Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet, so this can be reproduced?

Comment: If I remove one image, I am able to insert another. As you said, I have reached some sort of limit. But this limit has not documented.

Comment: Not all limits are officially documented. Also, I tried reproducing this, but I could not. I added 15k images (50 kB each) and I can still keep on adding new images to the sheet. Could you please provide more details about your spreadsheet, or provide a copy?

Answer (score 2):

actually, there is a limit of 100 MB and other sources indicate the limit depends on the pixel area

- **https://spreadsheetpoint.com/google-sheets-limitations/**
- **https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/07/10/limitation-of-images-for-inserting-to-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/**